# general formula for odes closely related $\sum_{i=0}^nf^{(i)}(t)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking to find a general solution to ODEs of the form:
$$\sum_{i=0}^nf^{(i)}(t)=0$$

---

for n=2 I obtained the solution:
$$y=\exp\left(-\frac{t}{2}\right)\left[A\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}2t\right)+B\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}2t\right)\right]$$
And they all follow a general form of:
$$y=\sum_{i=1}^nA_ie^{x_it}$$
where $x_i$ are the solutions to the equation:
$$\sum_{k=0}^nx^k=0$$
are there any way I can come up with a general formula for $y$ in terms of the respective exponential and trig functions? Thanks

Comment: The solutions to $1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^n=0$ are $e^{\frac{2\pi k i}{n+1}}=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n+1}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n+1}\right)$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Comment: You;re essentially looking for solutions to $\sum x^n=0$ which are zeros of $x^{k+1}-1$, except 1.